# Moved raspbian stretch to rpi0 from rpi3

Tags: raspbian

I had a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch and I disabled the USB ports and HDMI.

I did a image using Win32Disk because I had to give back the Raspberry Pi 3 and I brought my Raspberry Pi 0 and write the img on another SD Card.

But now after I boot the rpi0 the screen turn off (probably because I disable the HDMI in a file that inicializate with OS) and the RPI isnt connecting on my Wifi (dont know why) please can you guys help me ?

I need to continue with that .img (OS) and not do another one...

I can access the boot partition by windows, and I activate HDMI Safe mod from config.txt but didnt work anyway...

And I dont have a microusb hub to connect keyboard to configure it...

@Edit1 - Sorry if I was not clear.

The thing is, there is a file called rc.local in raspbian and I put many commands there to run after boot, like disable usb ports, disable hdmi, disable camera etc.
It was when I was with Raspberry Pi3, but now I have a RPi0 v1.3 2015 (without wifi) I didnt know about this different version of the same board, so I throught that rpi0, w and others were the samething.
Now I can't acess the RPi0 by SSH because it doesnt have a wifi, I cant use keyboard or anything usb because the only port probably is disabled and I cant see anything because rc.local run all the things that I already mentioned and disable the HDMI....

@Edit2 - [image] Now with that wifi adaptar can I configure the config.txt on Boot (FAT - can be r/w by windows) and put a command to connect on my wifi ?

@Edit3 - Thanks to @Ingo I created a pen drive with ubuntu 12.04 and could read the sdcard with admin priv and edited the rc.local.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Raspberry Pi 0 does not have wifi

Comment: Your headline says moving installation from RPi0 to RPi3 but you mean moving RPi3 to RPi0. You should correct it.

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yeah, you're right, I didnt know about it, but I think I can fix it with a mod or a Wifi USB, right?
I still need a way to modify the files after boot...

Comment: @Ingo, sorry, I fixed the headline.

Comment: What files to modify after boot? You don't say anything about it before. What exactly is the question now?

Comment: @Ingo, sorry, I did an edit on the post, can you read again. Its about the rc.local that run after boot. I'm not very good with english, so sorry about something wrong on the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out the SD Card from the RPi0 and put it into a card reader on another computer, that one you burned the image the first time. You must be able to read the **ext4** root partition (the second partition) on the SD Card. With a linux operating system (OS) that's no problem. You can simply mount it. If you do not use a linux OS you can boot one from a live CD, e.g. ubuntu or debian. When you have access to the root partition you can edit the `rc.local` file and disable all commands that prevent you to access the RasPi by USB and HDMI.

Comment: Right, I'll try to do it using ubuntu live so, but before I do it I did a thing to put a wifi adapter on rpi0 

Is there anyway to configure on boot (FAT/FAT32) config.txt and make it connect on my wifi?

Comment: @rSistema A wifi adapter can only be an usb to wifi adapter so you are lost with USB disabled.

Comment: makes sense, when I turn it on while it is on the boot the wifi adapter ping normally, but after end the boot it shutdown. 
I'm going to try exactlly you said to me to do. But I dont know so much about linux and commands to "mount" it. 

I have an notebok with card reader, unfortunatelly I dont have an usb to card reader. I hope that Ubuntu can identify it and save my life....

Comment: @rSistema I'm confident that Ubuntu will use the internal card reader. Just insert the SD Card and Ubuntu should automount it. Otherwise you can [ask google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Araspberrypi.stackexchange.com+mount+boot+partition+card+reader+laptop).